# APEX: How to store values after separating into a array and write them into a table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I've a `APEX` Item with DATA like `Test1:Test2:Test3:Test:4:CAR`

I'd like to separate them. After each ":" they should get a own row.

I realized this like this:

```
SELECT trim(regexp_substr(:P_69, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY instr(:P_69, ':', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0;
```

**Now i get:**

```
str
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
CAR
```

but now i want to insert Data in a table like `insert [... ...] when d.Test1 = Test1`

the `d.Test1` is from an other table than the information in my Apex ITEM.

Does anyone have a idea how this could be made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use [APEX_STRING.split](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/SPLIT-Function-Signature-2.htm) for splitting your item like:

```
SELECT column_value
  FROM TABLE(APEX_STRING.SPLIT(:P_69, ':'))
```

This you can also use in a join with another table that you should be able to use for your insert:

```
SELECT column_value
  FROM TABLE(APEX_STRING.SPLIT(:P_69, ':')) i
 INNER JOIN your_other_table d ON d.test1 = i.column_value
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have one more question. If i want a insert now i will need a loop right?

Comment: and another question if i want to store the "column_value" anywhere i need a array right? i thought of something like this:<br> 
`declare
type t_array is table of varchar2(200) index by integer;
l_array t_array;

begin

SELECT column_value into l_array
  FROM TABLE(APEX_STRING.SPLIT(:P_69, ':'));
  end;`

Comment: Oh now. My fault. I solved my problem. Here the solution: `INSERT INTO TEST (technology_id, system_id, sys_to_tech_desc)
SELECT ap.column_value, :P_69_System, :P69
  FROM TABLE(APEX_STRING.SPLIT(:P_69, ':')) ap;`